# How to specify which classes to be added in @SuiteClasses in junit4

Tags: junit, junit4

In Junit 4 we add test suites using annotations as mentioned below:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
A.class, B.class })
public class MyTestsuite
{
}
```

My query is, do we have any way to specify condition to decide which classes i wanted to include in the @SuiteClasses. For example; lets say in the above code, if i wanted to class A if some particular condition is true, else i don't want to add it to @SuiteClasses.

In junit 3.8 we do it using suite() method like mentioned below:

```
public class MyTestsuite extends TestCase
{
  public static Test suite()
  {
     TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
     if(some_condition_true)
     {
       suite.addTest(A.suite);
     }
     suite.addTest(B.suite);
     return suite;
  }
}
```

Is there any way we can achieve this using junit 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend Suite:

```
@RunWith(MySuite.class)//Customized
@SuiteClasses({
A.class, B.class })
public class MyTestsuite
{}
```

Define MySuite:

```
public class MySuite extends Suite {
           public MySuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
                    throws InitializationError {
                super(klass, builder);
                try {
                    filter(new Filter() {
                        @Override public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
                            return some_condition_true? true : false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String describe() {
                            return "...";
                        }
                    });
                } catch (NoTestsRemainException e) {
                    System.out.println("Hey, all test cases are not satisfied your condition.");
                }
            }
        }
```

plus: Although it can work, I recommend keep the test case simple. It is hard to maintain complex thing.

Comment: Say for example you process A.class and B.class, how can you pass values to MySuite to check for it?

Answer (score 0):

Shengyuan answer will work.

Another option is to always add the test class, but have an assumeTrue(condition) in your class that will decide when it should run and when it doesn't make sense.

(I like that approach better when the condition is related to test prerequisites: the test itself is the best place to know if it should run or not).